# If there exists an infinite derivative of a function can we call it a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If we define the existence of derivative that includes infinite limits of the difference quotient also,then if derivative is infinity or minus infinity at a point,is the function called differentiable as per the definition of differentiablity.(not derivability)

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite limits of the difference quotient"? Are you referring to the case where there is a vertical tangent, so the slope is infinite?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the case where there is a vertical tangent, i.e. when the limit 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\pm\infty,$$
then the function $f$ is *not* differentiable at $x=x_0$, since we still say that the limit does not exist.

Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_tangent) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A function is called differentiable if the (first) derivative exists (and is finite) at every point.

Infinite differentiability refers to the first, second, third, fourth,... derivatives existing at every point.

Comment: I did not mean that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying a function is or isn't differentiable it is usually more precise to say where the function is and isn't differentiable. Vertical tangents, corners, and discontinuities are places where functions are not differentiable. But these functions can be differentiable at every other point as long as they are continuous, the left derivative equals the right derivative and the function is defined at those points.